# How to listen for tap on DataRow inside DataTable in Flutter

Tags: datatable, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I was able to setup a DataTable to display a bunch of data. But want to navigate to another screen when a row is tapped.

Unfortunately there is no onTap callback for DataRow.

I ended up adding onTap for each DataCell which looks like a hacky solution. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Wrap it in a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: Can’t wrap it as DataTable property ‘rows’ expects array of DataRow s nor Widgets

Comment: I see. I guess you need to wrap the whole table and then figure out what row is below the position.Might be worth a feature request.

Comment: Any solution on this issue ? As I am facing the same

Answer (score 2):

The onTap call in DataRow is the onSelectChanged function

```
DataRow(
    cells: [
       DataCell(Text("ID"))
      ,DataCell(Text("NAME"))
    ],
    onSelectChanged: (value) {
     // insert your navigation function here and use the selected value returned by the function
      Navigator.of(context).pop(value);
    }
);
```